# Error while unlocking bootloader | FAILED (remote: 'Unlock failed - Err:0xffffffff')

Tags: adb, bootloader, fastboot, custom-roms

I was trying to unlock the bootloader of an old Redmi Note 4x, Downloaded fastboot and adb.
I first enabled developer option and turned on USB debugging. I tried finding OEM unlock option which was not present on the phone. After few hours of searching about it online, I finally concluded it is not available for the phone. So I went on and fired up my terminal [in administrator mode];

```
$ adb devices
> List of devices attached
> 8H4DZP69S44DQOEM        device
```

then I rebooted my device in bootloader (fastboot)

```
$ adb reboot bootloader
```

My Phone restarted in bootloader, then I went back to my terminal and checked if the fastboot was working or not;

```
$ fastboot devices
> 8H4DZP69S44DQOEM        fastboot
```

After confirming that the fastboot is running, I tried unlocking OEM;

```
$ fastboot oem unlock
> (bootloader) Start unlock flow

> FAILED (remote: '
> Unlock failed - Err:0xffffffff
> ')
> fastboot: error: Command failed
```

which.. well... failed and I don't know why. I tried searching this very error code online but failed to find anything close to it.

My other attempts like unlocking flashing failed in similar fashion;

```
$ fastboot flashing unlock
> (bootloader) Start unlock flow

> FAILED (remote: '
> Unlock failed - Err:0xffffffff
> ')
> fastboot: error: Command failed
```

```
$ fastboot flashing unlock_critical
> (bootloader) Start unlock flow

> FAILED (remote: '
> Unlock failed - Err:0xffffffff
> ')
> fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Nothing seems to be working, Please help!

Comment: It doesn't work because you use a tutorial not meant to be used with your phone. Search for a matching tutorial and you will notice that you need the "MiFlashUnlock" tool https://en.miui.com/unlock/download_en.html

Comment: I tried using MiFlashUnlock, when I try to sign in on my PC, it says that it needs to verify my phone number. And when I click on send CODE, the app prompts "Checking for security issues" and never stops loading. I still haven't got any OTP code, the tool is broken for me.

Comment: you need mi account bonded to phone and sim activated for 7 days - [RTFM](https://c.mi.com/thread-2262302-1-0.html) ;)

Comment: The sim has been with me for almost a decade now, created an MI account during the unlocking. But it seems to get stuck while sending the OTP code with a prompt "Checking for security issue" which never ends.

Comment: that's a broken [CAPTCHA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/mi-unlock-tool-checking-for-security-issues-stuck.4414465) use QR-Code instead @Thebluedragon there exist instant unlock methods but requires some basic linux skills (@ me if interested)

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine when I enter in MI website and put my phone number and verified it on the website. After this, I tried again, and then something happens differently.

However, in the next step, you are going to have to unlock something in developer options. It required internet from a SIM card, not WiFi. After this, enable OEM unlock in the developer options to run the program, and then you have to wait for 200 hours.

Comment: There's no "OEM unlock" option inside the developer option and I tried virtually everything I found on the internet.